# Why the screen is always black in SwiftUI ContentView

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have the following code in the content view in swiftui

```
  let screen = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentview") as? String
    let _ = print(screen, " IOS ")
    NavigationView{
        if (screen != nil){
            if (screen == "userview"){
                UserNameView()
            }
            if (screen == "usernameview"){
                let _ = print(2)
                PersonalInfoView()
            }
        }else {
            LogInView()
        }
        

    }.accentColor(.white)
```

However when the personal info view gets loaded it is always black. Am I doing something wrong.

The personalInfoView code

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonalInfoView: View {
  var body: some View {
     Text("OK")
  }
}

struct PersonalInfoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
     PersonalInfoView()
   }
}
```

Comment: works well for me, maybe some other code that you are not showing is responsible for your issue.

Comment: Note: that your logic (in if(screen != nil)), should include the case when it's not "userview" and not "usernameview".